# creating a list from excel sheet using foreach loop

Tags: c#, excel, foreach, arraylist, epplus

I am retrieving cells from an excel sheet, this is the output I get.

```
Cell A2 has value 113,295
Cell B2 has value 540
Cell C2 has value 41,044
Cell A3 has value 192,653
Cell B3 has value 510
Cell C3 has value 41,037
```

Code:

```
using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
{
    ExcelWorksheet sheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];

    //Select all cells in column d between 9990 and 10000
    var query1 = (from cell in sheet.Cells["A2:C2"] select cell);

    int count = 0;
    string[] s = null;

    foreach (var cell in query1)
        Console.WriteLine("Cell {0} has value {1:N0}", cell.Address, cell.Value);
}
```

My problem is that I want to create a class with members a,b and c and i want a List<> to hold a collection of these objects.

Currently, It is iterating but I don't know which cell is A, B or C in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a Partition method and give it the length of the rows... in your case 3

```
IEnumerable<List<T>> Partition<T>(IEnumerable<T> col, int partitionSize) {
 if (col.Count() == 0) {
  return new List<List<T>>();
 } else {
  var l = new List<List<T>>();
  l.Add(col.Take(partitionSize).ToList());
  return l.Concat(Partition(col.Skip(partitionSize), partitionSize));
 }
}

class TheClass {
 public int A, B, C;
}

return Partition(sheet.Cells["A2:C2"], 3)
         .Select(cells => new TheClass { 
           A = int.Parse(cells[0].Value),
           B = int.Parse(cells[1].Value),
           C = int.Parse(cells[2].Value)
         });
```

I hope this helps